# How to show $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|z^n|}=|z|$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

For $z\in\mathbb{R}$ it's very easy to show that it holds $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|z^n|}=|z|$$ But how do we show the same thing for $z\in\mathbb{C}$

Comment: $|ab|=|a||b|$.${}$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $z=re^{i\theta}$. Then $z^n=r^ne^{in\theta}$, and so, $|z^n|=r^n$, and $r \in \mathbb{R}$. So, you can now use your result from the case of reals.

Comment: I would be happy if someone who downvoted the answer could explain the reason for downvoting.

Comment: I wanted my rep to be an even number. (I lost divisibility by 5, the next prime is 3 but that'd be hard to work out! Hence 2)

Comment: Probably just the general bitterness going around in the other answer(s) (depending on whether they get or stay deleted).

Comment: @AlecTeal: And the way to do it was to downvote my answer :-P
Makes sense.

Comment: No I really like finding little things to do with my rep, I'm pretty sure that 1007 is prime. I'm really close to 999 right now - that'd be that 3 I want :P

Comment: @AlecTeal, I'm afraid that unless you delete your last offensive comments your fate in this site will be the same as that of user147453: ban. We all have the right to demmand respect from others, no need to violent. An apology won't be superfluous, too.

Comment: @DonAntonio someone got banned for having an answer with good maths that you didn't like. Don't brag about that, that was an act of spite and warning me of the same thing isn't much better.

Comment: @AlecTeal I believe that DonAntonio (and please correct me if I'm wrong) is referring to your comment in which you apparently admit to (in my opinion) a serious abuse of the voting system. I find it rather offensive that you would downvote a useful and mathematically correct answer solely for the purpose of making your reputation a pretty number.

Comment: @T.Bongers I honestly don't quite see why, if it made it negative I'd agree that'd be wrong, rep seems pretty arbitrary TBH. I'd worry about fixing the homework questions with 10s of votes and the decent ones with 0 and few views.

Comment: Not only I was referring to what T. Bongers mentions, @Alec: that "lucky bugger" naming doesn't seem a nice thing to say. About the rep. points: they are important **only** to give a rather general "overview" of the seriousness of a member. It is not a guarantee of good, elegant or even correct answers (oh, do I know this!), but rather of some confidence about questions being seriously, and professionally, addressed. Your whimsical downvoting affects this negatively. About the banning: apparently that was for the way that user used offensive speech, not for a good or bad answer.

Comment: @DonAntonio "Lucky bugger" is British slang for being envious and blaming something on luck. Like "Lucky sod" or "lucky blighter"

Comment: @AlecTeal Regardless, I don't really see how the existence of bad homework questions justifies your misuse of the voting system.

Comment: @DonAntonio another example, If I say "That's bollocks" I am saying it is bad, but "That's the dogs bollocks" is good

Comment: All commotion about peculiar downvoting practices aside, this answer is not optimal because the decomposition $z=re^{i\theta}$ is quite useless to prove the result. Instead, the identity $|z^n|=|z|^n$ yields $\sqrt[n]{|z^n|}=\sqrt[n]{|z|^n}=|z|$ and we are done. This is what @PedroTamaroff alluded to in a comment posted right from the start.